# how to write html and css compatible to different browsers and resolution

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, version, resolution

I am in the process of building a web-site with html and css.

Till now I viewed the code through my browser (explorer 10) and adjusted it in a way that it would look good on the browser. (Moved objects around, determine their size etc.)

Sadly, I recently discovered a bitter truth - the fact that everything look good and is in position in explorer 10 on my pc doesn't say anything about how it will look in different browsers or even different versions of the same browser.

I tried it on Chrome, explorer 11 on my laptop and tried to change the screen resolution- in all those cases the page didn't display as expected.
[Objects were misplaced, the cover photo didn't cover all the screen , etc.]

What properties in the css are responsible for compatibility in display between browsers, versions and resolution?

Those who have experience in web-developing - can you recommend a platform that makes the developing process easier? (maybe takes care of cross browsers compatibility and so on).

Something that is better than just starting from an empty html file.

Comment: You're basically asking how to become a web developer. That's waaaaaay too broad a question. There are no "properties in the css" responsible for compatibility. There' just css rules that COMPENSATE for specific bugs in various browsers.

Comment: explorer 10...????GOD save you mate....IE should be banned from web world....i suggest you do google for MDN tutorials(*that's Mozilla Developer Network*)!!!!! :)

Comment: I agree with @MarcB.  Although I am happy to hear that you are discovering these things, and that you realized Internet Explorer renders things differently than most other browsers, you should look into picking up a couple of books on the topic of "cross-browser web development".  At least search Google.

Comment: welcome to the jungle. it is pain in butt.

Comment: i thought there might be a narrow answer such as: "keep your width to 100%".

Comment: o.k. Thanks Guys.
didn't know it is such a big issue. (books and such). thought that maybe there is a quick solution

Comment: @mosh : no, its not that simple...HTML/CSS is no less than JAVA / PHP when it comes to understanding concept....and moreover, there is always *learning by experience*!! :)

Comment: @mosh: this is just advice based on personal experience, but for web developing, it's best to write standards-compliant html/css, and THEN "fix" it for specific browsers (in other words, introduce bugs into your code to compensate for the real world). Going standards-compliant to "hacked up" is far easier than starting "hacked up" and trying to fix your browser-specific code to work with other browsers. ALL browsers are "mostly" standards compliant anyways. But it's those "non-mostly" bits that will rip out your hair for you and start burning Bill Gates effigies.

Comment: I think you may be touching on Responsive Web Design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design There are loads of references at the bottom of that article that give more of an introduction to the subject.

Comment: thanks, i added a request for recommendation in the original question

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit lots of css cross browsers depending on how they each render the results. 
Read these two articles,

[CSS Mistakes](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/are-you-making-these-10-css-mistakes/)

[Cross browser coding](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/)

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason a great deal of web developers are using well known, mobile ready style libraries.  Your question is broad, however, there is no reason why a web developer cannot point you in the right direction.

Take a look at Twitter Bootstrap.  It's a mobile ready CSS/Script library which you can reference via CDN or you can install the library in your application.  Not only is it mobile ready, but it is cross browser compliant.  You will most likely be pleased with your results using Twitter Bootstrap styles.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/